# How can I end a here-document that starts with <<\\$fff?

Tags: shell, here-document

I was asked the following question in a test on shell scripting at my university, which never gave an answer, and google is of little help.

**Q:** What is the line separator that should be used to end this here-document?

```
fff=file
xyz <<\\$fff
...
```

Comment: Pedagogically, why would you put a question like that on a test? It's a corner case at best, probably a *worst* practice, and easily and habitually avoided by every "here document" writer ever. Sometimes you've gotta wonder about academics...

Comment: @Bruce: Pedagogically, because many students practice on and study from the many old exams that are readily available, and many students (and woefully many teachers) take a pattern recognition / memorization approach to learning (does anybody remember “flash cards”?) that leads to “educated” people knowing the answers to a large number of questions, and having some ability to adapt the answers to similar questions (e.g., if the answer to `<<EOF` is `EOF`, then the answer to `<<foo` must be `foo`) without *really* having the ability to *answer questions* or knowing the underlying theory.  … C’d

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So a teacher might strive to ask a question that isn’t trivially isomorphic to last year’s question (e.g., changing `<<foo` to `<<bar` is trivial) and that *does* challenge their understanding of the underlying rules and mechanisms.  That said, I agree with you; for a person to be able to answer that in a closed-book exam, he would have had to memorize every word of `bash(1)`.  I personally, would have guessed that `<<$fff` would have a terminator of `file`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This relates to a pet peeve of mine.  I don’t know what the problem is — it seems like some teachers have such a poor grasp of the theory themselves, that they compensate by teaching a million specific examples *instead of* teaching the theory.  I applaud test questions like “What is the library function that writes number to the standard output in a human-readable way?” and “What is the `printf` conversion type (i.e., the letter after the `%`) for printing floating point numbers?”.  I ***disapprove of*** questions like  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  “What is the *exact, complete* `printf` conversion specification to print a floating-point number with five character positions to the left of the decimal point (including `-` sign if appropriate, and leading spaces if necessary) and two digits to the right of the decimal point?” (unless it’s an open-book test).  I believe that there’s no benefit to *memorizing* the `printf` specs to that level of detail.  The first couple of times you need to print a floating-point number, you’ll check the man page.  If it’s something that you do often enough, you’ll *learn* it through repetition.

Comment: And the elephant in the room is the meta-question: “Why did the OP need to ask this question?”  He says he searched the Internet, and it’s no surprise that he didn’t find *this specific question* answered anywhere, but he should have found `bash(1)` and many other relevant documents.  I’m willing to give him a break on account of the language barrier (although there are probably plenty of translations of useful documents).  But does he have access to a system running `bash`?  What are the conceivable answers?  `fff`, `$fff`, `\$fff`, `\\$fff`, `file`, `\file`, and `\\file`.  Try them all.

Comment: @G-Man - much obliged for the thorough and well-thought-out answer to what I had assumed was a rhetorical question.  Sometimes rhetorical questions have answers, I reckon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line which ends the here document is

```
\$fff
```

From the `man bash` section on Here Documents:

> The format of here-documents is:

```
          <<[-]word
                  here-document
          delimiter
```

> **No  parameter  and  variable  expansion**,  command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion **is performed on word**.  If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>newline</kbd> is ignored, and <kbd>\</kbd> must be used to quote the characters <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>, and <kbd>`</kbd>.

`word` does undergo quote removal, so `\\$fff` is dequoted to `\$fff`. But, as the manpage says, no variable expansion is done so it stays that way.

The body of a here document might or might not undergo variable expansion and backslash interpretation. In this case, since `word` contains a quoted character (that is, the backslash), parameter expansion and backslash dequoting are *not* performed on the text of the here document.

However, the input is compared with the terminating sequence before variable expansion, so it is not necessary to backslash-escape the <kbd>\</kbd> nor the <kbd>$</kbd> in the terminating line.

Comment: typo? - `\$file` ?

Comment: Re your last sentence, _"As a result, it is not ..."_.  Your preceding sentence refers to the body of the `here document`, not the terminator.  The terminator - called the delimiter in `man bash` - is, as per your quote from `man bash`, _"the  delimiter  is  the result of quote removal on word"_

Comment: @Peter.O: Correct on both counts. Only backslash-newline escape processing is performed prior to comparing the delimiter (and in this case, that's irrelevant because the quoted backslash inhibits escape processing).

Answer (score 4):

The terminator is

```
\$fff
```

I'm going to assume that that's what @rici meant to say. 
As his penultimate paragraph says,

> `word` does undergo quote removal, so `\\$fff` is dequoted to `\$fff`.
>   But, as the man page says, no variable expansion is done so it stays that way.